# mismatched file size in unix ar command

Tags: c, fread, unix-ar

I'm working on a C program that can read the contents of a unix archive file. I have an interesting bug that maybe I don't understand so I thought I would ask in here.

It seems to me that the file size for the archive c.txt is off by one. Possibly because of the double return. The following is the contents of the archive file when opened in nano:

```
!<arch>
b.txt           1359332639  502   20    100644  28        `
Appending B. shortb long b

c.txt           1359332646  502   20    100644  17        `
COpy this shit.


d.txt           1359332655  502   20    100644  28        `
Appending D. shortb long b
```

The file size is listed as 17, but that only carries me to the \n before d.txt. The result is that when I scan through the list of files using fseek with file size, I end up crashing at d.txt

Below is the code for -t in C. This doesn't crash but the file_name for d.txt comes it as \nd.txt

When I try to create the verbose version I'm really running aground with this bug.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong in processing the file, or if there is another nuance that I'm not getting.

```
void table(char *archive){
    printf("\nI'm in -t!\n");
    size_t readNum;
    long long arch_size, file_size;
    char header[60];
    FILE *fp = fopen(archive, "r");
    if (!fp)
        fail('f');

    //get file size
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    arch_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    //move over ARMAG
    if(fseek(fp, strlen(ARMAG), SEEK_SET) != 0)
        fail ('z');

    //loop over files
    while(ftell(fp) < arch_size -1){
        //reads header into
        readNum = fread(header, 1, sizeof(header), fp);
        if(readNum != sizeof(header))
            fail('r');

        printf("%.*s\n", 16, header);

        file_size = atoll(&header[48]);

        //move over file
        if(fseek(fp, file_size, SEEK_CUR) != 0)
            fail ('z');

    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, your problem is almost surely that you're opening the file in text mode and newline conversion ugliness is corrupting your file offsets (and possibly your files). Make sure you use "rb" rather than "r" to open it in binary mode.

Comment: You are storing text files. Are you sure the originals do end in '\n'? That might throw off code that expects "decent" text files. Also make sure you can handle binary files.

Comment: As long as it's not a pre-OSX Mac, Mac uses POSIX line-ending rules, so the issue's probably something else..

Comment: I switched all of my io over to binary "wb" "rb" and that appears to have cleared everything up. Thanks!